# Given 1 recording of my voice, how can I process it to sound like 2 independent recordings of my voice played in unison?

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, phase, speech-processing, stft

I have one recording of my voice $x[n]$ singing a song. One thing I could do is independently record me singing the song again to obtain $y[n]$. Then, $z[n] = \frac{1}{2}\left(x[n] + y[n]\right)$ would sound like a "chorus" of some sorts (assuming that both recordings were done in perfect sync).

My question is, without doing a bunch of independent recordings, is there some decent way to go straight from a single recording $x[n]$ to the 2-fold chorus $z[n]$? More generally, I'd like to be able to go to a $k$-fold chorus (equivalent to averaging $k$ independent recordings).

My gut tells me one could simulate independent recordings by randomizing the phase in $x[n]$'s STFT somehow, but I'm not sure of specifically what should be done. In this regard, the only relevant method I'm aware of is [Paul stretching](http://hypermammut.sourceforge.net/paulstretch/), which doesn't really fit the bill, I think.

Also, is there a standard name for this particular effect I'm trying to create?

Answer (score 2):

To make it sound natural you typically introduce some small random pitch, speed & gain modulations. That's not a trivial amount of work, especially if you want something that sounds natural and good and maintains the original phrasing.

This is a pretty common plug-in in audio processing. It's typically called "vocal doubler" or "voice doubler" and there are many off-the-shelf options available. Here is an example: https://www.izotope.com/en/products/vocal-doubler.html. No endorsement or commercial interest, but you can't beat the price :-)

Comment: I absolutely appreciate being referenced to the nomenclature/tools to achieve the effect. But more importantly, I'm looking for the hard math that goes into making it happen. What are the actual DSP techniques/algorithms that go into making it happen, in terms of the original signal $x[n]$?

Comment: @chausies Look into the Phase Vocoder algorithm that can change tempo and pitch— use that with random variation and add to your original

Comment: @DanBoschen But I feel like an independent record $y[n]$ wouldn't simply have a different pitch/tempo than the original $x[n]$. It's more like, if $X[n, k]$ is the STFT of $x[n]$, then an independent recording $y[n]$ would have $Y[n, k]$ with the same frequency content but a randomly offset phase content (an offset that's somewhat randomized across each phoneme in the recording)

Comment: Yes I agree and certainly if it had a different tempo you would not be able to combine it. I was thinking of a randomized tempo variation with the mean change being 0 and also relatively small and perhaps equally random offsets in pitch that it provides the random phase offset you seek. I have never done this nor have audio processing expertise but thought the Phase Vocoder reference may be helpful to you.

Comment: @chausies an alternative to the phase vocoder would be the STRAIGHT vocoder. It is a very mature vocoder, with a lot of papers supporting its properties and I believe it is open source now. Also, you can do similar things with sinusoidal models (googling the terms will do the work). The main idea however is still the same: generate some small variants of your original recording and add them together.